# Reading and Processing Millions of documents

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, bigdata, data-storage

I have 1 Million+ documents stored on a Cloud Storage and I want to annotate these documents by some application and then storing the result into the DB. This data is one time loaded and not any real time data, Data might be updated once in a week.
My Approach: So what I have done and trying to implement is:

- List all the documents and store with their path in MongoDB with a flag to process
- Writing some code to read the files which have flag to process
- Get the result for the file and store it in MongoDB
- Read the document from DB directly

This approach is very slow and taking a lot of efforts. 
My Question is: **How can I faster the process of listing all the documents and cleaning and then passing to the Application for annotation and then storing it in DB?**
So just want to explore whether I can use some other tools as well to reduce coding efforts to achieve this process.